# Qt development lib and crossplatform screen capturing is it true?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, qt, console-application

Will it capture desctop [image] for me on all platforms if I'll port my windows VS 2008 console app code into Qt app compatable code (I have a console app so I hope it will not be a big trobule to port it into Qt console app)?

Comment: I mean I will not have to live my VS with Visual Assist X to ceate a project compilable and working across platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're asking if

```
QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId())
```

would work on different platforms, then yes it does. I've tested it on my windows and x11 systems and it worked as expected.

hope this helps, regards